# Save Radio button selection to String Array

Tags: android, arrays, string, radio-button

I am working on a Quiz App where I have 20 multiple choice questions. I have to store checked Radio button value to a String Array so that I can use the answers selected by user later in the App. Below is the code to get the text of the radio button. Now how can I save these 20 selections to an array ?

```
if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {
                RadioButton uans = (RadioButton) findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                String ansText = uans.getText().toString();
}
```

Comment: there is only one screen containing 20 ques or different screen for different questions ?

Comment: @ManishMenaria it's one screen I am using String Array for questions and options and user has to click next to go to next question

Comment: activity remains the same?

Comment: @ManishMenaria yes, activity remains same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save them in a arrayList of Strings
where the index of the question is also the index of the answer in the array

```
ArrayList<String> answersStringArray= new ArrayList<String>();

    if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {
        RadioButton uans = (RadioButton) findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        String ansText = uans.getText().toString();
        answersStringArray.add(ansText);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could declare HashMap to save check box value one by one

```
 HashMap<String,String> hm=new HashMap<>();
```

use `hm.put(question_number,checked_answer);` to add new value to HashMap when radio button is checked

use `hm.remove(question_number);`to remove value from hashmap if question is unchecked again after checking it

you could traverse the HashMap  like this after completion of quiz

```
for(String key :hm.keySet()){
     System.out.println(hm.get(key));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you get the quesText?

try to use a HashMap

```
HashMap<String,String> mMap = new HashMap<>();
if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {
    RadioButton uans = (RadioButton) findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    String ansText = uans.getText().toString();
    mMap.put(quesText,ansText);
}
```

if you just only save the answers, u can use ArrayList

```
ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {
RadioButton uans = (RadioButton) findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
String ansText = uans.getText().toString();
mArrayList.add(ansText);
}
```